# Fastlane timed publishing in Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, fastlane

I´m trying to enable Timed Publishing option for my fastlane production upload to the Google Play Store.

My actual Fastfile looks like this:

```
  lane :production do |options|
    desc "Increment build number"
    android_set_version_code(version_code: google_play_track_version_codes(track: "production").last + 1)

    desc "Building development"
    gradle(task: "clean")
    gradle(
        task: "assemble", 
        build_type: "Release",
        print_command: false,
        properties: {
            "android.injected.signing.store.file" => "keystore_file/keystore",
            "android.injected.signing.store.password" => "keystore_pass",
            "android.injected.signing.key.alias" => "keystorey_alias",
            "android.injected.signing.key.password" => "keystore_alias_pass"
        })
    upload_to_play_store(track: "production", rollout: "1")
  end
```

As far as I know, the supply command can provide the `automatic_release` parámeter but `upload_to_play_store` doesn't. Is `validate_only` the equivalent to `automatic_release` on this command?

I want to upload the apk directly to the production track without promoting other apps from beta nor internal.

Is there a way to achieve this?